# How to enable fields one by one based on previous field selection using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and I want to enable the field one by one as below.

After selecting country name, then only state menu as to be activated. After selecting state name, then only city name should activated.

Once click on submit button the selected value should be used to create a JSON string to get the response.

Comment: `<div id="stateMenu" ng-if="model.country">...</div>`. >hat is the concrete problem? Where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this :

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.countries = ['foo', 'bar'];
    $scope.data={};
    $scope.cities = [{name:'foo1', country:'foo'},{name:'bar1', country:'bar'},{name:'foo2', country:'foo'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <select ng-options="country for country in countries" ng-model="data.country"></select><br/>
   <select ng-options="city as city.name for city in cities | filter: {country:data.country} " ng-disabled="!data.country" ng-model="data.city"></select><br/>
   {{data.country}} - {{data.city.name}}
</div>
```

Just use `ng-disabled` as long you don't have any countries. 
If you're fetchingdata from the server on each level, don't use the filter that i put.